# Why does self-defined macro not work with argument from let?

Tags: clojure, macros

This macro

```
(defmacro readn
  [n]
  `(list ~@(repeat n '(read))))
```

works as I expect if I call it e.g. with

```
(readn 2) ;; expands to (list (read) (read))
```

However if I call this macro within a let, it does not work anymore:

```
(let [N 2] (readn N))
;; CompilerException java.lang.ClassCastException: 
;; clojure.lang.Symbol cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
```

I have already tried `,n` `'n` and `~n` but this led to no success. I think this is because the `N` is defined at run-time and the macro works at compile-time?

Putting it in eval like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984726/set-let-macros-nuts) yet does work:

```
(let [N 2] (eval `(readn ~N)))
;; expands to (list (read) (read))
```

I know I could do something similar using loop, yet loop seems (at least to me) kind of terse.

How do I make this macro work and how do I achieve the sketched behaviour, respectively? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273333/in-clojure-how-to-apply-a-macro-to-a-list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I think this is because the `N` is defined at run-time and the macro works at compile-time?

Yes, that's correct. You can think of it this way: when Clojure evaluates a form, it first completely macroexpands the form, then it evaluates that macroexpanded result. Starting with your example:

```
(let [n 2] (readn n))
```

Since [`let`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/let) is a macro, Clojure expands it:

```
(macroexpand-1 '(let [n 2] (readn n)))
;=> (let* [n 2] (readn n))
```

Now `let` has bottomed out to the special form `let*`, and the expression for `n` (`2`) isn't a macro, so Clojure doesn't need to expand it.

However, the body form `(readn n)` *is* a macro form. Remember that macros get passed their arguments *unevaluated*, so in this case your `readn` macro literally receives the symbol `n`.

```
(macroexpand-1 '(readn n))
;=> java.lang.ClassCastException
```

Macros are just functions that run at compile-time, so this...

```
(defmacro readn [n]
  `(list ~@(repeat n '(read))))

(macroexpand-1 '(readn 2))
;=> (clojure.core/list (read) (read))

(macroexpand-1 '(readn n))
;=> java.lang.ClassCastException
```

... is equivalent to this:

```
(defn readn [n]
  `(list ~@(repeat n '(read))))

(readn '2)
;=> (clojure.core/list (read) (read))

(readn 'n)
;=> java.lang.ClassCastException
```

My recommendation would be to just not use a macro at all here. A function would work perfectly well in this case:

```
(defn readn [n]
  (doall (repeatedly n read)))

(let [n 2] (readn n))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, for the explanation as well as the working code. I was always struggling with repeatedly and consorts to get the described functionality... very elegant.